# Delete function (commit editingStyle function) cause crashing the application once the swipe delete button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Im working on a project in swift 3.0 and Im fetching data from **core data** on to two tableViews namely;'**recurringIncomeTableView**', and '**otherIncomeTableView**'. However when 'commit editingStyle' function is activated (once I slide the row), I can deleted the particular row in 'recurringIncomeTableView'. But when i slide a row in 'otherIncomeTableView' and pressed **delete**, in the line 'let task = stores [indexPath.row]' causing the problem and the app is crashing. The code as bellow.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyIncomesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var recurringIncomeTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var otherIncomeTableView: UITableView!
    //var myIncomeType : String?

    var stores = [UserIncome] ()
    var other = [UserIncome] ()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.recurringIncomeTableView.reloadData()
        self.otherIncomeTableView.reloadData()
}

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        stores.removeAll()
        other.removeAll()

        let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "UserIncome")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false



        do {

            let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [UserIncome]

            print("Results from the fetch request are : ", request)

            // check data existance
            if results.count>0 {
                print("results are :", results.count)

                for resultGot in results {

                    //lets check if the data is available and whether the loop is working by printing out the "name"
                    if let incName = resultGot.incomeName {
                        print("expence name is :", incName)

                        //set the value to the global variable as to filter the arrays 
                        let myIncomeType = resultGot.incomeType

                        if myIncomeType == "Recurring Income"{

                          stores += [resultGot]
                          print("my recurring income array is : \(stores)")
                        }else if myIncomeType == "Other Income"{

                          other += [resultGot]
                          print("my other income array is : \(other)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.recurringIncomeTableView.reloadData()
                self.otherIncomeTableView.reloadData()

            }

        }catch{


            print("No Data to load")
        }


    }
   @IBAction func addIncome(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Add Income Button Clicked")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowAddIncomeVC", sender: nil)
        // Do whatever you need when the button is pressed
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.recurringIncomeTableView {
            print("recurringIncomeTableView count is ", stores.count)
         return stores.count
        }else {
            print("otherIncomeTableView count is ", other.count)
         return other.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == self.recurringIncomeTableView {
        let cell: RecuringIncomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recurringIncomeCell") as! RecuringIncomeTableViewCell

        let store = stores [indexPath.row]

        cell.incomeNameLabel.text = store.incomeName
        cell.amountLabel.text = store.amount



        //cell.textLabel?.text = myExpensesArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell

        }else {
            let cell: OtherIncomeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "otherIncomeCell") as! OtherIncomeTableViewCell

            let otherIncomes = other [indexPath.row]

            cell.incomeNameLabel.text = otherIncomes.incomeName
            cell.amountLabel.text = otherIncomes.amount


            //cell.textLabel?.text = myExpensesArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell

        }
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //performSegue(withIdentifier: "editStore", sender: nil)

    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "editRecurringIncome"{

            let v = segue.destination as! AddIncomeViewController
            let indexPath = self.recurringIncomeTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let row = indexPath?.row
            v.store = stores[row!]

        }else if segue.identifier == "editOtherIncome" {
            let t = segue.destination as! AddIncomeViewController
            let indexPath = self.otherIncomeTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let row = indexPath?.row
            t.store = other [row!]


        }
    }

//    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    //For remove row from tableview & object from array.
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            **let task = stores [indexPath.row]**
            context.delete(task)
            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            do {
                stores = try context.fetch(UserIncome.fetchRequest())
            }catch{
                print("fail")
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()


    }

}
```

Comment: You need to include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing the `other` array, not the `stores` array when deleting from the other table?

Comment: from which table you are deleting your row ? `self.recurringIncomeTableView` or `self.otherIncomeTableView` ? also please mention your crash in your question.

Comment: Sir the app is crashing only when deleting a row from 'self.otherIncomeTableView'

Comment: Please try to specify tableView in this function as well. if tableView == self.recurringIncomeTableView .....

Comment: As i mentioned above the particular line that causing the crash is 'let task = stores [indexPath.row]'

Comment: As @Paulw11 said. You should access the the `other` array. Can you please try to check from which `tableView` you are deleting just like you are doing it in `numberOfRowsInSection` and then access the correct variables.

Comment: How many rows do you have in every tableView? And which rows are you trying to delete?

Answer (score -1):

As per your `Core data` fetch request code.

You have to store `core data` object in your store array than & than you can delete that object directly form store array.

**You need to fetch object like this :**

```
// Initialize Fetch Request
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()

// Create Entity Description
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("UserIncome", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)

// Configure Fetch Request
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

store = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
```

After getting all data you have to filter your array with your requirement and display it in tableview I have just give example how to show that data in `tableview`.

**Show your data in cell like this :**

```
var data: NSManagedObject = store[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject
Cell.textLabel?.text = data.valueForKeyPath("Name") as? String
```

**Delete your data as per your code :**

```
let task = stores [indexPath.row]
context.delete(task)
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
```

it will help you to understand flow of `core data` with `tableview`.

Comment: This is has some missing parts. If you fetch the data only when the `viewController` loads you should delete it from the context and remove it from the array. (you aren't removing it from the array)

Comment: that part user need to implement as I have just mention where he is doing mistake and by this he can come out from crash. so not required extra detail fro this @ELKA

Comment: Sir can u put the complete code. the above code has missing parts as u said it seems.

Comment: didnt work bro much appreciate the effort. I think Im missing something